# Adding an executable to the linux command list

Tags: command-line, fedora

Sorry, I know its been asked before, but how do i add an executable to the command list for the command line?

Such that typing: `my-application`
will have the same effect as `/home/user/path/my-application`

I know i have to add a `.Desktop` (or was it a symlink?) file to a specific directory but i can't recall which one.

Please, can someone point in the right direction? I tried googling it and all i get are manuals for various commands

Answer (score 6):

There is more than one way to skin this cat:

1. You can put a symlink to your binary in a directory that is already in your PATH (`/usr/local/bin` for example).
2. You can modify your PATH to include the directory with your binary in it. One way to do this is add the following to `~/.profile`:

   `PATH="$PATH:/path/to/directory/" 
   export PATH`
3. You could even add an alias: `alias <commandName> </path/to/your/binary>`. Add it to your .bashrc file to recreate the alias when you log in.

There are probably other ways I haven't though of as well.

Comment: Just figured it's worth noting that many people add `$HOME/bin` to their `$PATH`, as `/usr/local/bin` requires root privileges to modify.  While this may not benefit the original questioner, it should serve to help anyone who may perchance run into this same issue on a system on which they do not have root access (such as a public shell server).

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `/usr/local/bin` for my commands (or for links to them). That directory is usually in the `PATH` variable, which means that when you type a command the system looks there for it.

To create a link to the command:

```
ln -s /home/user/path/my-application /usr/local/bin/
```

Alternatively you can move the command to that path instead of linking. You need root permissions to do it anyway.

After that it should work.